# Ansible Nested loop, Help needed

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to take input from the user, group name of servers separated by a comma:  abc, cde in variable destination, and then I want to loop over all the servers of each group and check for each server access on given ports. Here port is the variable that I created and stored in a file. I am trying to loop over all servers of the group in the *port* variable and for each of them check for all ports under that particular group in the *port* variable.

*port* variable in vars file looks like:

```yaml
port:
  abc: 
    - server1
    - server2
  abc_port:
    - 22
    - 34
  cde: 
    - server3
    - server
  cde_port:
    - 122
    - 343
```

I expect the result:

```
curl -kv server1:22
curl -kv server1:34
curl -kv server2:22
curl -kv server2:34
curl -kv server3:122
curl -kv server3:343
curl -kv server4:122
curl -kv server4:343
```

For servers of group abc and cde as per the group input by user which will be of form "abc ,cde"

How can I achieve this?

```yaml
task: 
  - name: check port opening
    shell: curl -kv {{item[1]}}:{{item[2]}}
    with_nested:
      - "{{destination.split(',')}}"
      -  "{{port.+item[0]}}"
      -  "{{port.+item[0]+_port}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the list of the destinations first. If you declare *dest* in the command line, e.g. `-e dest='abc,cde'`

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dest_port: []
    - set_fact:
        dest_port: "{{ dest_port + item.0|
                                   product(item.1)|
                                   map('join', ':')|
                                   list }}"
      loop: "{{ _dest|zip(_port) }}"
      vars:
        _d: "{{ dest|d('') }}"
        _dest_keys: "{{ (_d|length > 0)|ternary(_d.split(','), []) }}"
        _port_keys: "{{ _dest_keys|product(['_port'])|map('join')|list }}"
        _dest: "{{ _dest_keys|map('extract', port)|list }}"
        _port: "{{ _port_keys|map('extract', port)|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
dest_port:
  - server1:22
  - server1:34
  - server2:22
  - server2:34
  - server3:122
  - server3:343
  - server:122
  - server:343
```

Now, you can iterate the command

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "curl -kv {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ dest_port }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: curl -kv server1:22
  msg: curl -kv server1:34
  msg: curl -kv server2:22
  msg: curl -kv server2:34
  msg: curl -kv server3:122
  msg: curl -kv server3:343
  msg: curl -kv server:122
  msg: curl -kv server:343
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Vladimir, It worked and as a beginner got to learn new things.